# Are nested child routes in combination with named router outlets not supported in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Fellow-coders,

I have the following routing table:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'main', component: MainComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'spaceoverview', component: SpaceOverviewComponent, outlet: 'mainview' },
            { path: 'create-menu', component: CreateMenuComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
            { path: 'create-space', component: CreateSpaceComponent, outlet: 'mainview' },
            { path: 'update-menu/:id', component: UpdateMenuComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
            { path: 'update-space/:id', component: UpdateSpaceComponent, outlet: 'mainview' },
            { path: 'empty-menu', component: EmptyMenuComponent, outlet: 'sidebar' },
            { path: 'empty-main', component: EmptyMainComponent, outlet: 'mainview' },
            { path: 'update-categories', component: ChangeCategoriesComponent, outlet: 'mainview' },
            {
                path: 'permissions/:id', component: TestComponent, outlet: 'mainview',
                children: [
                    { path: 'create-reader/:id', component: CreateReaderComponent, outlet: 'top' },
                    { path: 'reader-overview/:id', component: ReaderOverviewComponent, outlet: 'bottom' },
                    { path: 'empty-top', component: EmptyTopComponent, outlet: 'top' },
                    { path: 'empty-bottom', component: EmptyBottomComponent, outlet: 'bottom' }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

They are all child routes of main, permissions also, except it has it's own child routes.

Unfortunately I can't seem to get it to work. I tried so many things already...

Loading a non-nested child with:

```
this.router.navigate(['/main', { outlets: { 'sidebar': ['update-menu', id], 'mainview': ['update-space', id] } }]);
```

is no problem, the corresponding url becomes:

```
http://localhost:4200/main/(sidebar:update-menu/123//mainview:update-space/123)
```

But when I try to load the permissions child route, with named router outlets, like:

```
this.router.navigate(['/main', { outlets: { 'mainview': ['/permissions', this.id, { outlets: { 'top': ['create-reader'], 'bottom': ['reader-overview'] } }], 'sidebar': ['update-menu', this.id] } }]);
```

It just won't load...

Does the Angular 2 router support nested routes using named router outlets, or am I bumping against the boundaries of it?

Please help a frustrated Angular 2 coder...

Comment: Did you solve this? Have got the same problem